# Why am I getting this error? This is the first question of kickstart 2020 (allocation) in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

    void bubbleSort(int arr[]) 
    { 
        int temp=0;
        int n = arr.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
                { 

                    temp = arr[j]; 
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
                    arr[j+1] = temp; 
                }
            }
        }

    } 

    int value(int arr[],int B)
    {
        int a=0,b=0;

        Main ob=new Main();
        ob.bubbleSort(arr);
        b=b+arr[a];
        while(b<=B)
        {
            a++;

            b=b+arr[a];
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=sc.nextInt();
        int N,B;
        int ar[]=new int[T];
        Main ob=new Main();

        for(int a=0;a<T;a++)
        {

            N=sc.nextInt();
            int arr[]=new int[N];
            B=sc.nextInt();
            for(int b=0;b<N;b++)
            {
                arr[b]=sc.nextInt();

            }

            ar[a]=(ob.value(arr,B));

        }
        for(int a=0;a<T;a++)
        {
            System.out.println("Case "+"#"+(a+1)+": "+ar[a]);
        }
    }

}
```

Program runs on bluej but not on their site.
**ERROR**

```
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Solution.java:2: error: class Main is public, should be declared in a file named Main.java
public class Main
       ^
1 error
```

Comment: What don't you understand in `class Main is public, should be declared in a file named Main.java`? Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: Yes i dont understand what that actually means.

Comment: You seem to have a public class named `Main` in a file named `Solution` either rename the file to `Main` or the class to `Solution`

Comment: BlueJ is for learning Java language and works around many issues that are not direcly contributing to learning the language. If you want to write actual production level java code that you should use a proper IDE and google the errors thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Main` has to be in a file with the name *Main.java*. 
In Java, the filename should always be identical with the name of the public class within.

Comment: I changed my class name to Solution. Now it gives me Runtime Error

Comment: Without the error message, it will be difficult. Furthermore, I think you have to start a new question.

Comment: Runtime Error- Test Case skipped